# Installing packages without docs

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to install a bunch of packages, but I don't want to install the documentation of them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

### Exclude documentation from .deb installation (DPKG)

- Onetime option: `--path-exclude` could be used to filter out unwanted files when installing a package:

  ```
  dpkg -i --path-exclude=/usr/share/doc/* ...
  ```
- Permanent solution: Create a file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nodoc` which specifies the desired filters. Example:

  ```
  path-exclude /usr/share/doc/*
  # we need to keep copyright files for legal reasons
  path-include /usr/share/doc/*/copyright
  path-exclude /usr/share/man/*
  path-exclude /usr/share/groff/*
  path-exclude /usr/share/info/*
  # lintian stuff is small, but really unnecessary
  path-exclude /usr/share/lintian/*
  path-exclude /usr/share/linda/*
  ```

### Skip recommended dependencies (APT)

Then change `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptics` or create new file containing:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

By the way, this is the permanent option of [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/541066/26246) for this question.

### References:

- [Reducing the size of the Debian Installation Footprint](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian#Remove_unwanted_files_at_install_time)
- [Ubuntu Wiki: ReducingDiskFootprint](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReducingDiskFootprint)
- `man dpkg`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with apt? I am using the `apt-get` command to install my packages

Comment: @Rob3 yes, i've update answer. setup conf files then use the command/tools you want.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the `doc` packages are recommended by the main package, but aren't hard dependencies. If they were hard dependencies (for example, `texlive-full`), I don't think there's a safe or simple way. For recommended packages, the answer is simple:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends <package-name>
```